# Conditional assignment of SHELL variable in Makefile

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I have a Makefile variables VAR_1 and VAR_2.

I need to assign the value of $($VAR1)_VAR2) to FINAL_VAR, ONLY if $($VAR1)_VAR2) is NOT EQUAL TO /dev/null. If $($VAR1)_VAR2) is EQUAL TO /dev/null then FINAL_VAR should be assigned some default value say "/usr/tmp"

Comment: How this is related to SHELL ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GNU make, you can use the `ifneq` directive:

```
ifneq ("$($(VAR1)_VAR2)","/dev/null")
    FINAL_VAR=$($(VAR1)_VAR2)
else
    FINAL_VAR=/usr/tmp
endif
```